# Just like google has official stats for os versions/devices, any apple stats for % devices using ios5 / 4.x?

Tags: ios

Is there any official apple(ios) stats about the % of devices having 5.x and 4.x ios version just like google has for android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know there are no official stats. But some programmers have given out some number. Eg Marco Arment from Instapaper: http://www.marco.org/2011/11/30/more-ios-device-and-os-version-stats-from-instapaper

These numbers are not very up-to-date. But you get at least an impression.